# For subgroups $H,K$ of $G$ if $HK$ is always a subgroup, is $G$ abelian?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

This is a well known theorem from elementary group theory.

> Let $G$ be a group and $H,K\leq G$, Then $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $HK=KH$.

As a consequence of this, if $G$ is abelian, then $HK$ is always a subgroup.

I am curious, if we can say the other way around. If $HK$ is always a subgroup for subgroups $H,K\leq G$, is $G$ necessarily abelian?

This is my progress so far. If $G$ has no nontrivial subgroups, that is $G\{e\}=G$ surely is a subgroup, but then $G$ is necessarily abelian. Because if it wasn't, then it is also not cyclic thus has a nontrivial subgroup.

We wish to show that $gh=hg$ for all $h,g\in G$. So maybe we can consider $\langle g\rangle, \langle h \rangle$. But what next?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is also well known that $HK$ is a subgroup if at least one of them is normal. And so a counterexample will be any non-abelian group having all subgroups normal, a.k.a. a hamiltonian group. For example [the quaternion group $Q_8$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group).

**EDIT:** I was too hasty to claim that $pq$ groups satisfy your condition. Removed from the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure that $S_3$ works. What if you take H and K to be generated by two different transpositions? Then $HK \neq KH$, and we can also see that $HK$ is not a subgroup: it has exactly 4 distinct elements.

Comment: @CharlieCunningham you are right. Actually I think that the condition is equivalent to hamiltonian. Apply it to $H$ and $\langle g\rangle$. I will confirm it later.

Comment: I think what we are looking for is [Iwasawa groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iwasawa_group), which contain the Hamiltonian groups but also some others. They've been classified, but examples don't seem easy to name in a single comment.

Comment: I think the smallest example has order 16: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/M16 All its subgroups are normal, except a pair of conjugates groups, and their product is a subgroup.

Comment: @CharlieCunningham I've never heard about these Iwasawa groups. Great finding, thank you!